# not work magento checkout email in payreto payment methode

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I set Payreto Payment method in my magento web site. Then i can All checkout process done but not get Checkout E-Mail Admin or User.

So, Please Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `app/code/community/Payreto/controllers/ResponseController.php`

and go to

```
 private function _getPostResponseActionUrl(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order) { and find Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($order->getQuoteId())->setIsActive(true)->save();  and Put 

if ($order->getCanSendNewEmailFlag()) {
                try {
                    $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    Mage::logException($e);
                }
            }
```

So Working Email Admin and User Both.